# Python 3 - How to produce a truly unique hash string as index for millions of rows?

Tags: python, mysql, hash, uniqueidentifier

I'm in a conundrum to decide what's the best way to insert a unique identifier for every row within a database containing over 60 million rows (and this is just one such dump, with similar sized ones arriving every month).

The table (which I later import into a python dictionary) looks like this right now:

```
- id
- deviceTimeStamp
- data1
- data2
- ...
- dataN
```

So far my strategy has been running the gamut on a random number concatenated with the `deviceTimeStamp` and then SHA-256 hashing it. *(BTW, security is not an issue here, for the record. We're driving the rows into a mining engine, but as they are realtime IoT data, there are at times certain rows which have the same `deviceTimeStamp`. Also, `deviceTimeStamp` has milisecond information.)*

I run a loop and do the following (adding only relevant parts of the script):

```
import random
import hashlib
import mysql.connector   

for row in cursor: 
   rng = random.SystemRandom()
   randNo = rng.randint(100000, 999999)
   id_string = "%d-%s" % (randNo, mydict['deviceTimeStamp'])
   scan_idbytes = str.encode(id_string)
   unique_id = hashlib.sha256(scan_idbytes).hexdigest()
```

After doing this, I realized that it might be the case that we could have the same hex digest for different rows, which beats the purpose of having a unique ID column. Any ideas or recommendations?

Comment: Why use a hash if it's just for a unique identifier? Use the row number

Comment: @NickA: for future proofing purposes, there is a chance this data would be stored into a NoSQL database. And there might be collisions if we end up using the MySQL row number as the unique identifier

Comment: Just add the current timestamp in the mix + a running counter

Comment: How big are these rows? You could hash the row data, rather than just using a timestamp & a random number.

Comment: @PM2Ring: not that big, but excellent idea!

Comment: While a hash collision with SHA-256 is certainly possible, the odds are extremely slim. Of course, if you want to reduce the odds you can just use a bigger hash. ;) AFAIK, there isn't a fast way to ensure that you don't have a collision: you have to test each hash against all the existing hashes.

Comment: @PM2Ring Is it performance-wise also "wise"  ?

Comment: @omrakhur https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Answer (score 1):

`uuid.uuid4()` will do.

See [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) for more information.

```
>>> import uuid
>>> id_ = uuid.uuid4()
>>> print(id_)
UUID('762008dd-7aa7-4537-bd30-3e2d5fc81362')
>>> str(id_)
'762008dd-7aa7-4537-bd30-3e2d5fc81362'
>>> uuid.uuid4().hex
'762008dd7aa74537bd303e2d5fc81362'
```

Answer (score 1):

Building upon comments above, I've created a unique identifier using `uuid` and then run a SHA-256 hex on it to obtain a (possibly) random number:

```
mystring = str(rng.randint(100000, 999999)) + str(uuid.uuid1())
scan_idbytes = str.encode(mystring)
unique_id = hashlib.sha256(scan_idbytes).hexdigest()
```